# Send mail to @hotmail.com/@live.com with JavaMail

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, outlook.com

I develop a application on android to send email. I want to use account MSN to send mail but it not send and error code on debug as below:
[image]

My configure on property are:

```
systemProperty.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
systemProperty.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
systemProperty.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.live.com");
systemProperty.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

The password and email address are correct and i ever test with other host are work except MSN.

Comment: check the configurations, what is the error u are getting !

Comment: the configurations not error my email and password are correct but it have problem when i sent. it show error code as above when i print the debug smtp.

Comment: where is error code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like JavaMail isn't able to figure out your host name correctly, although I don't know why it would think "????" is your host name.  Set the mail.smtp.localhost property to the correct host name for your machine.  See the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) for details.

Comment: What problem do you have with the localhost property?

Comment: My code is stupid i initialize with not correct values on localhost property. It work normally with gmail and yahoo but crash with Microsoft account. One more thing the smtp of Microsoft account is: `smtp-mail.outlook.com`

Answer (score 1):

There seems nothing wrong with your configuration. `501 5.5.4 Invalid Address` can be occuring because of the possible reasons below

- The `To` email address is wrong in format (like check if it violates the possible combinations of email addresses. Eg., "My Name" - try simplifying it to myname@live.com and try
- It might be bouncing email address
- Check the library you use for sending this, how and what it allows

Comment: the email is corrected and is it possible, it not allow us to send email by other application anymore?